# Ternary inside conditional component is not re-rendering on prop change

Tags: reactjs, redux

A parent is conditionally rendering a component with unique props. The ternary inside the render function of the child receiving those props is not working as expected.

I have used componentWillRecieveProps to setState and try to let the ternary be based on the state instead. And, after researching, I changed my code to use the function getDerivedStateFromProps (as componentWillRecieveProps is considered unsafe?) The code follows.

Additionally, I know that the component received props correctly and that state is updating to the correct value (due to a console.logs);

```js
    class AppearTyping extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            underscore: '',
            header: true
        }
    }

    .
    .
    .

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, currentState) {
        if (currentState.header !== props.header) {
            return {
                header: props.header,
            }
        }
        return null
    }


    render() {
        let display = this.props.paragraph.join('');
        console.log(this.state.header);
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.header ? <h2 className="about white">{display} 
    {this.state.underscore}</h2> : <p className="about white">{display}</p>}
            </div>
        )
    }
    }
```

If the component receives the `prop: header = true`, I want the `{display}` and `{this.state.underscore}` to be wrapped in `h2` tags. Otherwise, I want the component to be wrapped in `p` tags.

Comment: Do you have any other code in your component that sets the state

Comment: Can you also include how you are using the AppearTyping component in the parent? When you say it is "not working as expected" - does that mean that AppearTyping is always rendering p tags, even when header is set to true, or are you encountering some other sort of unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without actually seeing the code for how you are using the `AppearTyping` component by the parent, it's not exactly clear what unexpected behavior you're seeing, However, I was able to get the `render` method to switch between `h2` and `p` using a ternary conditional on the state.

My `render` method looks like this:

```
render () {
  let display = this.props.paragraph.join('')
  console.log(this.state.header)
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.header ?
       <h2 className='about white'>{display} {this.state.underscore}</h2> :
       <p className='about white'>{display}</p> }
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/92jowv85ow) that shows the code in action**.

By the way, since you are primarily switching on *which* component to use (`h2` or `p`), did you know that you could also just conditionally select the component based on the state? This will help you remove a little bit of code duplication.

```
render () {
  let display = this.props.paragraph.join('')
  console.log(this.state.header)
  const WrapperComponent = this.state.header ? 'h2' : 'p'
  return (
    <div>
      <WrapperComponent className='about white'>
        {display}
        {this.state.header ? this.state.underscore : null }
      </WrapperComponent>
    </div>)
}
```

Comment: I was passing in the string "true" and "false". I switched those props to bool this morning. But I'm giving you the answer for the WrapperComponent. I am going to remember that. Thank you for the extra tip!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this should work, also this looks neat and clean.

```
render(){
 let display = this.props.paragraph.join('');
 console.log(this.state.header);
 const content = this.state.header ? 
              <h2 className="about white">
                   {display} 
                   {this.state.underscore}
              </h2> : 
               <p className="about white">
                   {display}
               </p>;
  return <div>
            {content}
         </div>;
}
```

try to keep your `return` lean.